# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in my Google Chrome JavaScript console

Tags: javascript

So I understand the above error means my browser is not recognizing a function I'm attempting to call. My question is why this is happening in my particular instance. I'll post the relevant code and maybe you guys can help me.

I have a function

```
function homepage_screensaver()
{
    // ... bunch of lines here .... 
    var circwrapper = new Array(mycirc, theta);
    document.setInterval(move_obj(circwrapper, papwidth, papheight), 100);
}
```

which, as you can see, calls another function that I'm building right now:

```
function move_obj(obwrap, bckwid, bckht)
{
     var c = obwrap[1]; 
     var t = obwrap[2]; 
     var bb = c.getBBox(); 
     // ... bunch of lines here ...      
}
```

The error I'm getting is on the `var bb = c.getBBox();` line.

I have a hunch. I think the problem has to do with me trying to wrap an object in an array and then unwrap it and call a function on it. Maybe the browser can't find the object's member function because of the fact that it has no idea what type of object it is in the first place.

(I know the fact that I created a wrapper class is functionally useless, but it is for my own readability.)

Anyways, what's the solution here?

Comment: For one thing, you're using `setInterval` improperly. You need to pass a function to it. You're invoking the function instead. Put your call inside an anonymous function.

Comment: Furthermore, Array indices start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @cookiemonster WHOOPS!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I feel like such a n00b for making that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simply that `obwrap[1]` (which is `theta` outside the function) doesn't have a `getBBox` property. You probably intended to access `obwrap[0]` (which is `mycirc`). Also, your array doesn't have an index `2`, so the following line should probably be changed to `obwrap[1]`.

*However*, once you solve that problem, your code will immediately have another problem in a different place:

The way your code is currently written, `setInterval` will try to invoke the result returned by `move_obj(circwrapper, papwidth, papheight)`. Your code is the same as:

```
var result_of_move_obj = move_obj(circwrapper, papwidth, papheight);
setInterval(result_of_move_obj, 100);
```

Note that `move_obj` is called only once, and then the *result* of `move_obj` is called periodically thereafter.

If the `move_obj` function ends with `return undefined;` (or not have a `return` statement, which is the same thing), then `setInterval` will try to invoke `undefined`, which obviously won't work.

Instead, you want to wrap your call inside of an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() { move_obj(circwrapper, papwidth, papheight) }, 100);
```

Comment: This would seem likely, but the questioner claims that the error is being caused by this line `var bb = c.getBBox();` which would imply that `c.getBBox` was `undefined`. If so that's a differetn cause than what you've answered.

Comment: @AlexWayne Whoops! I was solving the problem that the OP is *about* to have, but doesn't currently have, because his current error halts execution. I've added a solution for the OP's current problem as well; thanks.